# Работа с геоданными Python

Tags: python, геолокация

Есть такие данные: координаты автобусных остановок и координаты станций метро. Нужно создать буфер вокруг станции радиусом 500 метров, выгрузить остановки по координатам и найти пересечения остановок в радиусе 500 метров от станции метро. 
Подскажите в сторону каких библиотек смотреть.